# My Div isn't styling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried lots and it still won't style! My css looks like this:

```
#subnav {
background: url(../_img/subnav.png);
height: 36px;
width: 455px;
margin: -15px 0 0 25px;
position: absolute;
}
.subnav {
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 6px;
color: #676767;
padding: 8px;
}
```

and my html looks like:

```
<div id="subnav" class="subnav">
        testing 123
        </div>
```

and it looks this way:

[image]

**Side-Note:** I was wondering what's the most efficient way of coding that navigation with the sub-nav? I'm kind of outdated with my html/css at the moment.

"the white bit in the picture above is my sub-nav and the blue bit is the navigation so upon click options are shown in the white bit"

LAYOUT: http://uploadir.com/uploads/v8qafb1w/downloads/new

Comment: What about it is different from what you are expecting? The `#subnav` styles appear to be all there except for the background image.

Comment: is your css file valid? Perhaps you have an error someone in the end of the file that is causing it not to read the end of the css (assuming this is at the tail end).

I would also check your subnav as an inline stylesheet rather than loading it from an external source. That way avoids cache issues (just for testing purpsoses obvs)

Comment: Sorry, I meant my class isn't styling. Look at .subnav and the font/size etc.. None of it is styling.

Comment: Why do you have an id and a class for the same html element ?

Comment: @Mak I've literally tried everything. I've done it other ways too and it's just not working lol.

Comment: try to put the exact same css you defined in .subanv in #subnav and check if it renders.

Comment: @KennyDuncan Most likely there's another CSS rule somewhere that's taking precedence. Please reduce the problem to something that we can reproduce: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KennyDuncan: The CSS and HTML you've posted here are valid and work as *Mak* said. So there must be something else bugging. Indeed it could be a misplaced `}` somewhere.

Comment: I honestly don't see anything that could interfere with this.. I might just do a CSS reset?

Comment: You can check what css rules and in what order are applied and which ones are overwriting others by right-clicking on the element (submenu) and selecting "Inspect Element" in Chrome. Other browsers have this functionality as well. Then select Elements tab and check styles in right hand window.

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest of putting all css under one rule #subnav to make things simpler to debug.

Comment: Try validating your html and css.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5wmas9
That's what I see.

Comment: In the inspector your class is set to sn. not subnav. should be subnav in th html.

Comment: I added the layout to the OP, you can download and take a look. I'm almost about giving up because it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the image that you showed us is different to the content that you have present in the question.

You have sn as your class in your html and you are trying to reference subnav via css

Answer (score 0):

To add a sub menu I would personally use the following.

```
<ul>
<li>
    itsHabbo
</li>
<li>
    Radio
    <ul>
        <li>
            AM
        </li>
        <li>
            FM
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    Events
</li>
<li>
    Forum
</li>
```

So you basically have you sub menu within the item you wish to select.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have sn class not subnav. I changed to sn in you code and you can now see styling

```
<div id="subnav" class="sn"> come at me bro     </div>
```

Comment: I fixed that and it still doesn't show any difference. Starting to think it's the server or something.

Comment: This should be an issue in the browser side not the server. Try different browser also do the hard refresh on your browser